# manipulating tensorial data in Abaqus ODB

Tags: python, tensor, abaqus

I want to sum all the Strain Energy Density (ELSE) values of every mode (Frames from modal analysis) of my odb and save it in a new Frame.

My code works fine with the displacements 'U' and type=VECTOR
But when I change it to 'ELSE' and type=TENSOR_3D_FULL I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    File "..\Python\modaldata.py", line 62, in <module> 
    newField.addData(field=strechtMode1)  OdbError: Fields are not compatible. They are either associated with different structural models or have incompatible attributes.
```

Do I have to use another method to manipulate tensorial data? I found something with position=ELEMENT_NODAL but with a total differen approach by getting certain scalar stress values of certain nodesets. I want the whole ELSE Tensor for every Integrationpoint of every Element as a new Frame.

Here is my code:

```
#-ODB OEFFNEN------------------------------------------------------------------------#    
odb = openOdb(odbName) 
#-DIE MODEN EINZELN ABSPEICHERN UM SIE VERRECHNEN ZU KOENNEN-------------------------#
nmoden=len(odb.steps['Modalanalyse'].frames)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#-FIELD VARIABLE ZIEHEN UND VERRECHNEN-----------------------------------------------#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

field='U' # ''ELSE' # U oder E oder ELSE oder whatever...
type=VECTOR #TENSOR_3D_FULL  # muss an das field angepasst werden. 

Modes_field=[]
for i in range(nmoden):
    Modes_field.insert(i,odb.steps['Modalanalyse'].frames[i].fieldOutputs[field])  
#-FIELD VARIABLE ALLER MODEN UEBERLAGERN---------------------------------------------#
sumAllModes_field = Modes_field[0]
for i in range(nmoden):
    sumAllModes_field = sumAllModes_field + Modes_field[i] 
#-NEUE FIELD VARIABLE MODE ABSPEICHERN-----------------------------------------------#
newFrame = odb.steps['Modalanalyse'].Frame(incrementNumber=0, frameValue=0.0)
newField = newFrame.FieldOutput(name=field, description='sum of ELSE of all modes', type=type)
newField.addData(field=sumAllModes_field)
#-ODB ABSPEICHERN--------------------------------------------------------------------#
odb.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

[ELSE](http://130.149.89.49:2080/v2016/books/usb/default.htm?startat=pt02ch04s02abv01.html) is a total energy.
Thus, its field output type is SCALAR. 
And that is why you get your error, you are trying to populate a TENSOR_3D_FULL field with SCALAR field values.

I strongly recommend using prettyPrint from the textRepr library in order to access a field and get a better idea of its properties.

```
from textRepr import prettyPrint as pp  

pp(odb.steps['Modalanalyse'].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['ELSE'])
pp(sumAllModes_field)
pp(newField)
```